# Integration evaluation running forever

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate a function but the evaluation goes on and on forever.

Here is the code:

```
Integrate[
(Cos[x] Log[1 + x] + Sin[x]^2)/(2 x Cot[x] + ArcTan[x]^2), 
{x, 0, Pi/2}]
```

Is it because the function is not defined at $0$ nor $\pi/2$?

Comment: There is likely no closed form.  Of course you can perform `NIntegrate` and get the numerical answer ($0.709459$).

Comment: Ok thank you very much!

Comment: on my pc it took 152 seconds (using the command 'Timing') to return the integral without evaluation!!!!!